# Access Array on HTML VIEW Laravel

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel

I've an error like Trying to get property of non-object, I use var_dump and realize that I've array not object but idk how to access

```
public function ptkp($id){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $keluhan = keluhan::findOrFail($id);

    $tindak = DB::table('tindakans')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('tindakans.id, id_keluhan, perbaikan_sementara, revisi_dokumen, target_verifikasi, ttd_tanggung1,
    ttd_tanggung2'))->get();

    $analisa = DB::table('analisas')
    ->join('tindakans','tindakans.id','=','analisas.id_tindakan')
    ->join('keluhans','keluhans.id','=','tindakans.id_keluhan')
    ->select(DB::raw('id_tindakan, analisa, tindakan, pic, tanggal_pelaksanaan'))->get();

    return view('Laporan.ptkp',compact('keluhan','tindak','analisa','halaman'));
    //$pdf = \PDF::loadView('laporan.ptkp', compact('keluhan','tindak','analisa','halaman'));
    //return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Look at $tindak when I use var_dump the result is array, in View I try to access using `<?php echo $tindak->perbaikan_sementara ?>` but error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in Laravel, I assume you use a blade templating engine, so you can try this in the view to access property of object :

```
{{ $tindak->perbaikan_sementara }}
```

Or if it's an array of objects :

```
@foreach ($tindak as $example)
   {{ $example->perbaikan_sementara }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really have an array it's in your Laporan.ptkp (better use laporan.blade.php instead)

`@foreach ($tindak as $item)
   {{ $item['perbaikan_sementara'] }}
@endforeach`